# Making images 300dpi from pngencoder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

HI i have flex + php app.

Also i understand that i only get 96dpi from image, because of my monitor dpi, but I need to make sure that even it generates 96dpi, it really is 300dpi quality. Can somebody advise?  I tried alivepdf, its not as good.

I am taking 28 original images from user and making a "thumbnail picture collage" out of it for printing.  I dont get the crisp quality in generated collage images, compared to originals.  Here are my function, can somebody help me improve my snapshot?  I really need to generate photo quality images for printing. Thanks

```
private function createImages(object:Object):void
{
    progress.text = "Start Generating Images ( "+(index+1)+" - 28 )";
    images_array.push(ImageSnapshot.captureImage(album.tilesList[index],30 0,new PNGEncoder()));
}

private function uploadImage(snapshot:ImageSnapshot,name:String):void
{
    var ba:ByteArray = snapshot.data;//PNGEnc.encode(snapshot);
    //send data as normal files
    ba.position = 0;
    var ID:String = name;
    var filename:String = ID+".png";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A monitor is 72dpi. If you want 300 dpi you should scale the image inside the pdf. 
Your scale ratio should be 1 / (300 / 72) = 0.24;

So if you put the image inside a clip and set scaleX and scaleY to 0.24 and make a pdf of it; it 'is' 300dpi.